# timestamp migration in sybase ASE 12.5 to 15.5 coupled with Solaris to Linux Server migration

Tags: database-migration, sap-ase

We are migrating Sybase ASE 12.5 database to ASE 15.5 coupled with Solaris to Linux server. We have hit a peculiar issue where column has a timestamp datatype. So for this column values which makes sense on Solaris doesn't make same sense on Linux server.

One way to deal with the issue is to just do a dummy update all the rows so that all the values for the timestamp column become meaningful.

I am not sure if there is any other way to bring back the original values for the timestamp column ?

If anybody has such experience please share.

Thanks,

Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

There is endianness issue between sparc and x86 architectures. If you use solaris machine which has sparc architecture, it uses the `big endian` and linux x86 architectures uses `little endian`.

Refer to http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/big-endian-and-little-endian

If your application is running os solaris sparc machine and stored data, you also need to migrate  multi-byte numeric data to little endian to get meaningful data on linux x86 systems.